# Optimization of a query sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a query but Diee takes a long time to get the data I do not know what it is you can simplify the query or optimize so that it runs more fluently?

```sql
SELECT
    Number,
    SUM(Price) AS PRICE,
    Pnr,
    MAX(DATE_FORMAT(orderdate,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) AS order,
    AL,
    AM
FROM
    order_name,
    user,
    card_user
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(orderdate,'%m%Y')
    AND
    order_data.cid= card_user.card_number
    AND
    order_data.cid = card_user.card_number
    AND
    order BETWEEN card_user.valid_from
    AND
    card_user.valid_to
    AND
    card_user.user_id = user.user_id
    AND
    order_data.BTYPE IN ('1','4')
GROUP BY
    card_number,
    P_NR,
    DATE_FORMAT(orderdate,'%Y%m%d'),
    AV,
    AK;
```

Thank you already for the answers!

Comment: Try to use only english in your question please (even if it is to thank us for our answers)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Maybe `date_format(max(ORDER_DATE), ...)` might be faster. The right indexes, see the MySQL`explain` command mentioned above.

Comment: What is the point of doing `DATE_FORMAT(orderdate,'%m%Y')` in the WHERE clause without comparing the result to anything?

Comment: @Joop donst work

Comment: Qualify each column with the table name (or alias) so we can tell where they come from.  It makes a _big_ difference in optimization.

Comment: If `orderdate` is a `DATE`, then you don't need the function in `DATE_FORMAT(orderdate,'%Y%m%d')`.

Answer (score 0):

First, many things wrong with the query, but not to complain, just explain as you are obviously new.  Here is your original query rewritten with more appropriate JOIN syntax.  How do you get from the first (LEFT) table to the second (RIGHT) table becomes the "ON" clause of the join.

Second, always try to use table.column or alias.column in your queries.  Those who do not know your table structures would otherwise be guessing at the source.  What is number.. an order number, credit card number, or just some other number?  Because your GROUP BY clause has CARD_NUMBER.  Similarly with Pnr, AL, AM.  No context on those.

Your where clause only had the conditions between the tables (now moved into respective JOIN clauses), but no actual limitations, so you are getting ALL records.  Your clause on the "order" between the credit card valid from/to date, I would hope and expect all purchases with credit card be within the credit card's valid expiration date, so you are getting all data.

If you mean to get records based on when they happened, you would want your ORDER Date to be within some dates... such as with an Order date since July 1, 2019, or From Jan 1 - June 30, 2019 or similar.  Your time is getting ALL records that are of "BType" either 1 or 4.  We have no idea what that type indicates, but that is your only criteria filtering being applied.

Your group by should be by all non-aggregate columns in the SELECT (columns) list.

```
SELECT
      Number,
      SUM(Price) AS PRICE,
      Pnr,
      MAX(DATE_FORMAT(orderdate,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) AS order,
      AL,
      AM
   FROM
      order_data OD
         JOIN card_user CU
            ON OD.cid= CU.card_number
           AND order BETWEEN CU.valid_from
                         AND CU.valid_to
            JOIN user u
               CU.user_id = U.user_id

   WHERE
          DATE_FORMAT(orderdate,'%m%Y')
      AND OD.BTYPE IN ('1','4')
   GROUP BY
      CU.card_number,
      P_NR,
      DATE_FORMAT(orderdate,'%Y%m%d'),
      AV,
      AK;
```

So, to answer with a question... I would edit your original post and ask you to fix the missing references of table.columnn or alias.column, but also in simple English description.. What are you looking for.  Ex:  I am looking for all orders within X and Y time period.  And for each person's credit card number, what was the most recent purchase.  Hopefully this question can move forward with such clarification.